# How can localhost and 127.0.0.1 share the same request in Django/Vue?

Tags: python, django, vue.js, cors, localhost

In my Django application, I'm authenticating a user on the backend, with port 8000. Upon success, the user is redirected to  the frontend on port 5173.

After configuring CORS and CSRF correctly, I was able to successfully reproduce this when I accessed localhost:8000/login. It redirected to localhost:5173/ and the authenticated content was provided.

The issue is however, when the user attempts to access the URL provided by Django (127.0.0.1:8000), it gets redirected to the localhost:5173 origin, meaning they don't share the same resources as they are different URLs.

Are there any practices or workaround in this scenario? Or is it assumed that the user should always be accessing localhost?

I tried to execute the same_site= None option, however, I believe that is for HTTPS which I have not configured yet

Comment: You can use devserver proxy to avoid cors, whether it's preferable depends on how it's supposed to work in production

Comment: What's preventing users from accessing the server via `localhost:8000` rather than via `127.0.0.1:8000`?

Comment: @jub0bs Nothing is stopping in them in all honesty. It was just something I was hoping to kind of link. localhost works perfectly fine. The behaviour of 127.0.0.1 produces incomplete requests.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks. I'll take a look into that